Entitiy Framework v9 timeout in update: Relation between # of records returned from linq and update time
I'm using this code to update some records of a table which has around 600k records:
var someRecords = myContext.Commits.Where(c => c.ProjectName == "BSA" && c.RepoName == "sales-SalesApplication-Command" && c.CommitterUniqueName == null);

foreach (var commit in someRecords)
{
    commit.CommitterUniqueName = GetUniqueName(commit.CommitterName, myContext);
}

myContext.SaveChanges();

The linq returns 346 rows and I strangely get a timeout error after 30 secs. This is strange because the same update using SQL Mgmt studio runs in no time:
update Devex_Commit 
set CommitterUniqueName = 'abc'
where ProjectName = 'BSA'
and RepoName = 'sales-SalesApplication-Command'
and CommitterUniqueName is null

When I look at the debug logs of EF, I see that it uses the Id field to update the records:
fail: 16.05.2024 14:17:56.737 RelationalEventId.CommandError[20102] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Failed executing DbCommand (30,026ms) [Parameters=[@p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [Devex_Commit] SET [CommitterUniqueName] = @p0
      OUTPUT 1
      WHERE [Id] = @p1;
fail: 16.05.2024 14:17:56.794 CoreEventId.SaveChangesFailed[10000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DevExDataJob.Models.DevexContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

When I slightly change the linq to return just one row, all works fine:
var someRecords = myContext.Commits.Where(c => c.ProjectName == "BSA" && c.RepoName == "sales-SalesApplication-Command" && c.CommitterUniqueName == null && c.Id == 123);

foreach (var commit in someRecords)
{
    commit.CommitterUniqueName = GetUniqueName(commit.CommitterName, myContext);
}

myContext.SaveChanges();

The debug log of EF in this case has no change:
info: 16.05.2024 13:48:42.897 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Executed         DbCommand (18ms    ) [Parameters=[@p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [Devex_Commit] SET [CommitterUniqueName] = @p0
      OUTPUT 1
      WHERE [Id] = @p1;

When I debug my original code which returns 346 rows, and bring the execution out of the foreach loop after only one record is updated, I still get the same timeout! This makes me think that there is a relation between the number of records returned from the linq and the time needed for the update operation. I'm totally confused..
I don't want to increase the timeout threshold of EF as the same update query runs in no time.
Please advise.

as you can see your query from ef runs for every entity so 365 times. And your db query makes somehow a bulk update. To achieve that in ef you can use ExecuteUpdate.
Example:
myContext.Commits.Where(c => c.ProjectName == "BSA" && c.RepoName == "sales-SalesApplication-Command" && c.CommitterUniqueName == null).ExecuteUpdate(s => s.CommitterUniqueName  = "ABC")

@KnApP993 thanks for the fast response, but your comment does not explain why I get the same timeout when I manually exit the foreach loop after one record is updated. I've further updated the title and the question to make it clearer.

the same update it's not the same update at all. EF is an ORM, not embedded SQL. The primary concept is the object, not the table. What you wrote loads all 365 objects in memory and changes them. When SaveChanges is called, EF detects all the changes and generates modification queries for every object, hence 365 UPDATE statements. Had you added or deleted some objects, EF would include INSERT or DELETE statements for them as well.

346 rows are not a lot though and would never result in timeouts UNLESS something else blocks the commands. This could be inefficient queries that take Shared locks on the entire table, explicit long-lived transactions in the query itself that block the transaction executed by SaveChanges. You can check what blocks your application in SSMS Activity Monitor. This shows the active queries and, in case of blocking, which connection caused the block. Once you find that you can check what that connection is executing.

As for the same update, in EF Core 7 and later that is the ExecuteUpdate method to perform batch updates. You can specify expressions for the setters provided they can be translated to SQL. What does GetUniqueName do? Perhaps you can convert it to an expression, or perhaps you can precalculate a "unique" number using ranking functions like ROW_NUMBER

the same update it's not the same update at all. EF is an ORM, not embedded SQL. The primary concept is the object, not the table. ORMs map operations and changes made to individual objects to individual SQL commands. The question's code loads all 346 objects in memory and changes them. When SaveChanges is called, EF detects all the changes and generates modification queries for every object.
That said, 346 UPDATEs aren't a lot. Something else must be blocking the transaction executed by SaveChanges. Some other inefficient query or long-lived transaction may have taken read (shared) locks on the rows you intend to update. Querying 600K rows without an index will scan (and thus lock) all rows while the query is running for example. You can use SSMS Activity Monitor to see which session (connection) blocks your own and what it executes.
The question's query may not be efficient for example, even if the filter columns are indexed, eg if most commits are in the BSA project. If they aren't, the server would have to scan the entire table, thus locking all the rows.
The equivalent batch update can be performed in EF Core 7 and later using the ExecuteUpdate method :
var query= myContext.Commits.Where(
    c => c.ProjectName == "BSA" 
    && c.RepoName == "sales-SalesApplication-Command" 
    && c.CommitterUniqueName == null);

query.ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(
             b => b.CommitterUniqueName , 
             "abc"));

This gets translated to a single UPDATE, equivalent to :
UPDATE Commits
SET CommitterUniqueName = 'abc'
WHERE
    ProjectName = 'BSA'
    AND RepoName = 'sales-SalesApplication-Command'
    AND CommitterUniqueName IS NULL

You can use an expression to calculate the new value as long as the expression can be translated to SQL, eg :
query.ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(
             c => c.CommitterUniqueName , 
             c => c.CommitterName + ":" + c.Id.ToString()));


I used ExecuteUpdate() as suggested (first by @KnApP993 so kudos to him and to Panagiotis for the detailed answer) and problem solved. This link also gave me the big picture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/
